# Login to a php site with curl

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to do a bash script to login to a php site via curl. In this way (always with curl) I will be able to download a file.

The site in question is this:

```
"https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login.php"
```

I thought I could use this command to login by sending a cookie:

```
curl --anyauth --user username:password https://web.spaggiari.eu/
```

and then try to download the file from this site using this command (The site below is where I should download the file from):

```
curl -v https://web.spaggiari.eu/fml/app/default/xml_export.php? 3Aclasse_id% 3A & gruppo_id =% 3Agruppo_id% 3A & ope = RPT & dal = 2020-11-03 & al = 2020-11-03 & format = xls
```

The output of the command though is this:

```
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558707881f50)
*   Trying 159.69.111.222...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149996 ms for 3 (transfer 0x558707881f50)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x558707881f50)
* Connected to web.spaggiari.eu (159.69.111.222) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.spaggiari.eu
*  start date: May 29 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 29 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "web.spaggiari.eu" matched cert's "*.spaggiari.eu"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /fml/app/default/xml_export.php?stampa=%3Astampa%3A HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.spaggiari.eu
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 19:30:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN;
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.spaggiari.eu https://ajax.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://code.jquery.com/ https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;frame-ancestors 'self' file: *.spaggiari.eu;
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pc6u2mc162b30ek2gp9u6phdpt7q85kv; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: ../../../home/app/default/login.php
< X-ZVersion: c
< Pragma: public
< Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
< 
* Connection #0 to host web.spaggiari.eu left intact
```

That's a redirection sending me to the login page.
So it tells that I have an authentication problem i think.
Now I don't understand what I have to do to be able to log in. I have the correct credentials, but I think I am doing something wrong with the command used.

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: if you visit the actual login page you will see that the authentication request is actually performed to https://web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd using a form POST (you can get the request details from your network console in -whatever browser you are using- devtools). Then, if the website performs authorisation based on a cookie it's up to you to send it in your subsequent request.

Comment: @36ve So should I use this command? "curl --anyauth --user username:password web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd" Thanks for the reply

Comment: @36ve or "curl --user username:password web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd"?

Comment: by default --user will perform a basic authentication which does not seem to be expected by your server see curl --data argument

Comment: @36ve Thanks for the reply. Using "curl --data username: password web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd" I simply get the content of the page: "{" error ": [" Wrong ID or password "]," api ": {" env ":" production "," AuthSpa ": {" version ":" 2.8.4 "}}}"

Comment: did you try to perform a login on the actual website and inspect the request with your network tools ??

you would see that the form expects the following fields

cid: 
uid:
pwd:
pin:

Comment: @36ve This is the link that is printed by the console when I log in correctly: 'https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login_ok_redirect.php'. If you want I can also send you other details of the request and the server response during the correct login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224080/discussion-between-tommy-and-36ve).